# Как завести псевдоним для типа данных с указанием максимальной длины?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Можно каким-то образом завести псевдоним для встроенного типа данных с указанием максимальной длины, например, `number(3)`?

Чтобы я мог объявлять переменные не так:

```
myvar number(3);
```

, а так:

```
myvar mynumber;
```

А еще атрибуты в типе `object`, вот так:

```
create or replace type myobject as object
(
   myattribute mynumber
);
```

Я знаю один способ -- завести таблицу со столбцом нужного типа:

```
create table mytable (mynumber number(3));
```

Теперь можно объявлять переменные:

```
myvar mytable.mynumber%type;
```

Но это же фу, как некрасиво. Особенно, пустая таблица, болтающаяся в списке нормальных.

А также этот способ не подойдёт для объявления типа атрибутов в типе `object`. Компилятор выдаст ошибку:

> Ошибка: PLS-00329: тип на уровне схемы имеет недопустимую ссылку на ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял из документации, то создавать подтипы для стандартные типов данных Oracle можно только на уровне PL\SQL, и использовать их  только в PL\SQL. А типы объектов создаются только на уровне схемы и, следовательно, подтипы использовать не могут, только стандартные типы данных. Так что, видимо, только вариант с хаком через <s>таблицу или другой</s> объект остается, как написали выше.

> Currently, you cannot define object types in a PL/SQL block, subprogram, or package.

[Oracle Built-in Datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54330)

[Using PL/SQL With Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm#i7530)

---

@4per это к варианту @0xdb

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER3
  AS
  OBJECT (value NUMBER(3)) FINAL;

CREATE TABLE TEST_T (
  ID NUMBER3 //созданный тип
);

INSERT INTO TEST_T (ID)
VALUES (NUMBER3(333));
```

> SQL1.sql: 1 Строка вставлена [0,001c]

```
INSERT INTO TEST_T (ID)
VALUES (NUMBER3(3333));
```

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this
>   column

т.е. такой вариант действительно работает

---

А по поводу "через другую таблицу" да, действительно не работает, извиняюсь.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_T (
  ID NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE TABLE TEMP_T2
(id TEMP_T.ID%TYPE);
```

> ORA-00911: invalid character SQL.sql 7 14

Comment: @Vladislav Khapin  А почему хак? Вполне нормальное определеие подтипа.

Comment: Да, неправ был. Просто сам мало с объектами и подтипами в таком виде не работал.

Answer (score 5):

Можно создать пользовательский тип данных с ограничением. Например, так:

```
create or replace type number3 as object(value number(3)) final;
/
Type NUMBER3 compiled

create or replace type mytype as object (short_id number3);
/
Type MYTYPE compiled

select mytype(number3(999)).short_id.value as short_id from dual;

  SHORT_ID
----------
       999

select mytype(number3(9999)).short_id.value as short_id from dual;
```

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Так как определён на уровне схемы, будет работать везде:

```
declare short_id number3 := number3(999); begin dbms_output.put_line(short_id.value); end;  
/ 
999
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412149/5574962

> Возможно, вы захотите использовать SUBTYPE.
>   Разместите объявление подтипа в пакете и используйте его.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYSUBTYPES_PKG IS
  SUBTYPE MYNUMBER IS NUMBER(3);
END;
```

Теперь можно, объявить переменную

```
myvar  mysubtypes_pkg.mynumber;
```

Но атрибут в типе `object` всё равно не получится.