# Как найти и обратиться к объекту БД Домен / DOMAIN?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

Очень мало информации нашел о таких объектах как "домены".

Я знаю, что это примерно ([маш. перевод: What is domain type in SQL?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-domain-type-in-SQL)):

> Доменом является определенный пользователем, названный набор значений.
>   Когда вы объявляете столбцы в таблице SQL или параметры для хранимой процедуры, вы можете использовать домен вместо встроенного типа данных SQL, а затем этот столбец или параметр ограничивается значениями, которые удовлетворяют домену.

Занимаясь сейчас анализом спецификаций к системе, встречаю в ней часто объявление доменов. Но по факту, в базе я не вижу их как объекты, либо упоминания в коде.

Comment: Где вы это взяли? Судя по граматическим ошибкам, это скорее всего  машинный перевод.

Comment: так и есть, когда искал информацию, забрел на сервис Quora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начнём с термина *Домен* (*domain*) [в контексте БД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)), цитирую:

> Домен в реляционной модели данных — тип данных, то есть множество допустимых значений.

Этот термин относится более к этапу анализа и дизайна логической модели БД.

В стандарте [SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) появилась возможность создать домен предложением `CREATE DOMAIN`.
Но это предложение реализовано только в некоторых СУБД, например, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdomain.html).

В СУБД *Oracle* предложение `CREATE DOMAIN` отсутствует, поэтому вместо термина *домен*, чаще в ходу термин -- *ограничение* (*constraint*, *contrained data type*). Самые часто используемые ограничения (например, по длине, набору символов) реализованны во встроенных типах данных [Built-in Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6).

---

Как же реализуются заложеные в логической модели данных *домены*, например -- пол персоны, широко известный как МЖ.

Набор данных для тех, кто всё хочет попробовать сам:

```
insert into person values ('Маша', 'f');
insert into person values ('Паша', 'm');
insert into person values ('Саша', null);
insert into person values ('Мики', 'd');
```

[**Check Constraints**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE)

```
create table person (
    name varchar2 (32), gender char (1),
    constraint chk_gender check (gender in ('f','m')));
```

В случае вставки недопустимого значения:

> ORA-02290: check constraint (DB.CHK_GENDER) violated

[**Referential Integrity Constraint (Foreign Key)**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE)

Несколько не в ногу со временем, но ранее широко практиковалось хранить допустимые значеия в отдельной таблице:

```
create table gender (val char (1) primary key);
insert into gender select trim (column_value) from xmlTable ('"f","m"');

create table person (
    name varchar2 (32), gender char (1),
    constraint fk_gender foreign key (gender) references gender (val));
```

В случае вставки недопустимого значения:

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (DB.FK_GENDER) violated - parent key not found

[**User-Defined Types**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7CF27C66-9908-4C02-9401-06C2F2C4021C)

Пользовательский тип данных с ограничением можно будет использовать как в SQL, так и PL/SQL контексте. Хороший пример есть уже в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593072/217579). Для случая с МЖ:

```
create or replace type genderType as object (
    val char (1),
    constructor function genderType (val char) return self as result) final
/
create or replace type body genderType as
    constructor function genderType (val char) return self as result is
    begin 
        if val not in ('f','m') then 
            raise_application_error (-20000, 'illegal gender value >'||val||'<'); end if;  
        self.val := val;
        return;
    end;
end;    
/
declare 
    gender constant genderType := genderType ('d');
begin null; end;
/
```

> ORA-20000: illegal gender value >d<